# Android Studio - Calculation comes to 0 despite not having any zero values in it

Tags: java, floating-point

I'm having a little problem in Android Studio with a calculation coming to a value of 0.0. I think I know why, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The calculation is as follows:

```
float energyConsumption = ((20*128/100)/1000)*(12*blocsRounded*24*365);
```

`blocsRounded` is calculated from user input, and with the test data, is evaluating at `62.0`, and I have checked this value to be sure it is working properly. That means, therefore, that this calculation should evaluate to `166,846.464`. But instead, I am getting an output of `0.0`. And I am 100% sure that I have the right value for `blocsRounded`, as I have output this to the console to check.

I assume that this has something to do with the way floating point numbers are stored (and changing this to a double gives me the same output of `0.0`), but if this is the case, then I'm not sure how to get around it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer divison is happening here. Multiply denominator with 1.0 make it float divison.try this

```
float energyConsumption = ((20*128/(100*1.0))/1000)*(12*blocsRounded*24*365);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I will accept your answer as soon as the time restriction passes. Although, I'm not quite sure _why_ it worked, o if you are able to give a quick explanation, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @mooseymanson In integer division 999/1000 = 0  because nemerator and denominator both are integer. but if you multiply any one with 1.0 then that thing become float and float divison occur so 999*1.0/1000 = 0.99 . hope you get it.

Comment: I think I understand, thank you. I thought because the whole thing was being cast to a float, that it would treat all values in the calculation as a float.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
(20*128/100)/1000
```

evaluates to `0`, because all the numbers are treated as of type `int`.  
Therefore `2560/100000` is `0`. 
You only have to indicate that the 1st number is of type `float` by appending to it the suffix`f`:

```
float energyConsumption = ((20f*128/(100*1.0))/1000)*(12*blocsRounded*24*365);
```